# PIC32MZ bootloader without development board

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming, microchip, bootloader

I would like to put a bootloader in a PIC32MZ2048ECG064. I found [AN1388B](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01388B.pdf), but in table 9 (available bootloader workspaces) it lists only PIC32MX devices as compatible. The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001191D.pdf) doesn't mention 'bootloader' anywhere. I didn't find anything in the other [application notes](http://www.microchip.com/wwwcategory/TaxonomySearch.aspx?show=Application%20Notes&ShowField=no#) either, nor did a Google search yield anything useful.

Is there a PIC32MZ bootloader? I would prefer an official one (although probably none exists), and one that works over serial port or USB - preferably not ethernet / SD card / USB host. Does something like that exist? I do not own a development board.

Comment: what bootloader you are looking for?. Why do you want a bootloader for PIC32MZ. Which type of applications you want to run on your MCU

Comment: @CZAbhinav Anything with which I can program the flash memory without needing the ICD3. That way, I'll only need the ICD3 (which I borrow from someone else) once and I can use the bootloader after that.

Comment: Do you have a development board for your MCU or you have your custom designed board

Comment: @CZAbhinav I'm currently working on a breadboard.

Comment: you want to burn your program onto your MCU?

Comment: @CZAbhinav yes.

Comment: why dont you Use a Pickit3 connector and make you own custom board for your MCU. Schematics for Pickit3 connector can be found in its user guide. Then develop your software and burn it using pickit3

Comment: @CZAbhinav that's not really a bootloader, that's a programmer. You know what a bootloader is, right? I want a piece of software that I can put in the boot section, which either runs the program from flash, or reprograms that flash upon some trigger. That way, I don't need an external programmer after putting the bootloader in. See [AN1388](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01388B.pdf) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The [Microchip Harmony](http://www.microchip.com/harmony) framework libraries have example apps of bootloaders for PIC32MZ devices.  These include USART, I2C, and USB examples.

The example apps in Harmony are normally located at:

C:\microchip\harmony\[HARMONY VERSION]\apps

Comment: Unfortunately, these projects require that you generate MISP16 code, which isn't supported by the free version of the XC32 compiler. When turning this option off, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @CamilStaps I think some of the MX versions require the mips16 to fit in the boot program space, but not the MZ version I am looking at.  Also, for most applications there is plenty of room to just move the bootloader to the regular program space flash.